# How to make commit in git

Tags: git, commit

I am new in git, but very want to learn this system. I typed command:

```
git commit -am "I`m worried"
```

and pressed Enter. But this was the result:

```
$ git commit -am "I`m worried"
>
```

What is it and how to exit and do my commit?

Comment: _i typed command <git commit -m "Some text">_ No, you didn't. State clearly and honestly what you _did_ do.

Comment: This is a bash problem, not a git problem.

Comment: Please recognise that showing what you did and what happened should be considered the bare minimum requirement for a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with what appears to be a backtick character in the commit message ("I`m worried").

The easiest way to fix this is to ctrl + c out of the dialog and use a new commit message. You can do something similar by using single quotes inside of double quotes instead. If you really want to use a backtick you can escape it in your message "I\`m worried"

Comment: Well, you might mention that one correct way to include a backtick is to use single quotes instead of double quotes. Another is to escape the backtick.